# Permissions within a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, medical, quorum

Everything I've been reading about blockchain from my understanding says that even on a private blockchain, every participant can view all transactions. I've seen it mentioned that a use case for block chain could be the sharing of medical data. So for example if I had a blockchain that holds the medical history of every person from birth to death in a country. Is there no way of setting up permissions so that only data relating to a person and those who have been given permission to that person's data can view it? If the data is stored on every node in a blockchain, how is a person's computer supposed to have the capacity to store the medical data of every person in a country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise looking up Medrec when related to health care.  Most of the research is geared towards dealing with keeping the data off the chain.  In addition, there are other blockchains that might provide a better solution, for more privacy, for example, I would look up quorum by JP Morgan.  There are different formats being looked at but these can give you two possible solutions.  Also, check out Health Nexus' whitepaper, it deals with medical blockchain technology.  Let me know if you need more.

https://www.pubpub.org/pub/medrec

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum

Answer (score 0):

There are blockchains that allow defining permissions. [Hyperledger Fabric](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects) is one of them. You have the ability to configure channels with data stored in the ledger of the participants in the channel only.

Answer (score 0):

to pass the scalability problem of blockchains and their solutions for this purpose, you should concentrate on off-chain architecture.

right now this scenario should be considered:

1. save tx's to the blockchain(it should be formal)
2. save hashed data to an off-chain repository like DB's.
3. save the address of that data-hash to blockchain for future access.

yeah, you pointed to the right thing. a central point of access as an admin-node or god should be the opposite of blockchain as a distributed dream.

for this issue, the mechanism like secret-sharing or re-encrypt proxy should be realized to guarantee the privacy and security of data-hashed.

for more information read this article:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210670717310685

Answer (score 0):

GoQuorum has an 'enhanced permissioning' model where you can do all that, and at the same time stay compatible with Ethereum standards.
Check this out: https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/configure-and-manage/manage/enhanced-permissions/